# Append formated text from SQL to TRichEdit

Tags: delphi, trichedit

Can you help with this problem?
How do I append a formatted txt from database field to a TRichEdit ?

Just to clarify:
I need to get the contents of 2 database fields that have formatted text (RTF) and put them in TrichEdit preserving the formatting.
I use MSSQL Express and the field are set as TEXT in ANSI format.

Ok this works nice:

```
  tmp := tblCases.FieldByName('Field1').AsString;
  str := tblCases.FieldByName('Field2').AsString;
  delete (tmp,LastDelimiter ('}',tmp),1);
  delete (str,1,1);
  ms := TStringStream.Create (tmp+ AnsiSTRing (#13#10)+str);
  ms.Position :=0;
  DBDX.Lines.LoadFromStream(MS);
  ms.Free;
```

Comment: `.SelText := 'I am appended if .SelStart := .GetTextLen' and blue if SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;`

Comment: 'Formatted text'? In what format is the text? In what field type is it stored (and in what database)?

Comment: I did try that however it will just paste a plain text. I tried to switch off the plain text like rtf.plaintext :=false and use stream but will just replace the text the RtF. i need formatting to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

To merge 2 RTF fields I removed the last closing } of the first and the first bracket of the second thus creating one string. then use the TstringStream to paste in the TrichEdit. see updated code above.